# for loop count monthly total python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a data and here has some date time.

like this:

```
datetime
2022-01-01
2022-02-01
2022-02-01
2022-03-01
2022-03-01
2022-03-01
2022-04-01
2022-04-01
2022-04-01
2022-04-01
2022-04-01
2022-04-01
2022-04-01
2022-04-01
2022-04-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
2022-05-01
```

I need to count monthly total so I do something like this

my code is:

```
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
example_per_month = []
for a in range(1,6):
    example = {}
    example[str(a)] = len(df[(df['datetime'] >= '2022-0'+str(a)+'-01')&(df['datetime'] <= '2022-0'+str(a)+'-31'))])
    example_per_month.append(example)
print(example_per_month)
```

And her is my output:

```
[{'1':1},{'2':2},{'3':3},{'4':9},{'5':14}]
```

But I need the total count month by month now.

expected output:

```
[{'1':1},{'2':3},{'3':6},{'4':15},{'5':29}]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please put your full code, what you've given doesn't show where df is created.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide an actual example instead of requiring everyone to piece it together from breadcrumbs. Both the input and output examples are not valid literals. The code implies the data is actually a pandas dataframe or similar, not a list of dicts; note that this implies one should *not* use a loop but a bulk operation to do such aggregations.

Comment: Why would the output include {'4':15} when there are only 9 occurrences for month 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not the exact solution you want but hope this will help you to find a solution

```
values = [{'1':10},{'2':20},{'3':30},{'4':9},{'5':14},{'6':37}]

loop = 1
total = 0
for val in values:
    total += val[str(loop)]
    val[str(loop)] = total
    print(val[str(loop)])
    loop += 1
    
print(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

"I need to count monthly total so I do something like this". I interpret this as meaning that the requirement is to count the number of dates that occur for any given month.

There is absolutely no need for heavyweight modules such as *pandas* for this.

```
FILENAME = 'foo.txt'
counter = {}
with open(FILENAME) as csv:
    next(csv) # skip header
    for line in csv:
        mm = line[5:7].lstrip('0')
        counter[mm] = counter.get(mm, 0) + 1
print(counter)
```

**Output:**

```
{'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 9, '5': 15}
```